# Setting a timeout for a async task

Tags: c#, async-await, timeout, task, dotnet-httpclient

I await an http request to and Node.js API in a task in C# as follows:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

string responseString = await (await client.PostAsync("https://......",content)).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How can I set the timeout for this task to 7 seconds before it should throw an exception if the server is down? I will handle the exception with a try catch.

Comment: Use a `TaskCancellationSource` to get a `CancellationToken` that will signal cancellation after a timeout.

Comment: What is the `client`? Is it `HttpClient`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(7000);
await Task.Delay(8000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Also, when you already have an external cancellation token, you can link them.

```
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(7000);
    using var linked = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationTokenSource.Token, cancellationToken);
    await Task.Delay(8000, linked.Token);
}
```

This way, whichever token gets cancelled first, triggers the cancellation.

In your case:

```
async Task DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(7000);
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        string responseString = await (await client.PostAsync("https://......", content, cancellationTokenSource.Token)).Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catched");
        throw;
    }

}
```

or

```
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(7000);
        using var linked = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationTokenSource.Token, cancellationToken);
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        string responseString = await (await client.PostAsync("https://......", content, linked.Token)).Content.ReadAsStringAsync(linked.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catched");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I implement that in my code above? As that code is in a try catch that gets handled, but it takes 40 seconds for it to throw the exeption.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework C# 7.3, and get a the following error "using declarations is not available in C# 7.3" This is for a desktop application.

Comment: @ChristoKruger Then you can wrap them in a body. `using (var disposable = new Disposable()) { }`